# Header() issue. Prints entire html document instead of variable

Tags: php, csv, header

Been twisting and turning on this for hours now, can't figure out how to make some sense of it.

I'm working in a php file round 6000 rows...

There's multiple header() calls before my switch case header call is executed.

The header() call works if I use ob_start(); and ob_end_flush(); at the top and the bottom of the document.

For some reason I don't understand, this:

```
$csv = urldecode($source['csv']);
$filename = urldecode($source['file']);     

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");   

print $csv;
break;
```

outputs the entire html-document instead of just the $csv variable which is supposed to print and save the .csv file for the client browser.

Ideas?

Note: the call is made from a php document -> posting -> $csv and $filename , they are both $_POST[].

Comment: Why is there an HTML document involved at all? Either you're outputting CSV or HTML, not both.

Comment: That's what im wondering, the variable only contains CSV-formatted data yet it the .csv file gets contains <html> and the CSV data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `exit` instead of `break`!

Otherwise other code after this can be executed.

Comment: I prefer `die;`. I can type a letter less.

Comment: it's in a switch case. break is usually standard?

Comment: The `break` there is correct in the context of switch. But It is also important that after delivering the file via header() to exit the code execution! So use `exit;` and after that `break;`.